# Access object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I am trying to access email and password field but i dont know where this `'0'` came. I am retrieving object from rethinkdb and it looks good without `'0'`. But  then am using Lodash `_.assign()` method like  this

```
var user = new User
var finduser ={}
dbuser = finduser  //  dbuser is  the  object retrieving from db
user = _.assign(user,finduser)
```

I am getting data like this

```
{
    '0': {
        'email': 'email@ymail.com',
        'pswd': 'kdkd'
    }
}
```

I just want to access email field

Comment: Is `user` an array?

Comment: What is input and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can access like this,

`user['0'].email`

or

`user['0']['email']`

Comment: If this is the idea solution to this question, should you not close it as dupe for *How to access key inside nested object*?

Answer (score 0):

you are retrieving array of data from database. That's how the `0` is coming. There should be a `.first()` method on `db` query or `ORM` you are using which will return single object of `user` not array.

Comment: well   when  i call method  from  db query  its  displaying normal  db  like this    {'email': 'sdsdsd'}  there  isnt any array